# How to partially mock a static method with void return to do nothing?

Tags: jmockit

Before with jmockit version 1.20, we can do the following to mock only "myMethod" (which is a static method with void return) for class MyClass, and it makes myMethod do nothing:

```
@Mocked("myMethod") MyClass myClass;
```

Looks like this is not supported in the latest version 1.33.  I wonder how to achieve the above (partially mocking a static method with void return to do nothing) in the new version?

Comment: Take a look to partial mocking: http://jmockit.org/tutorial/Mocking.html#partial

Comment: The link above is no longer valid.  It's moved [here](https://jmockit.github.io/tutorial/Mocking.html#partial).